# TV and STB programming

Tags: javascript, television, samsung-smart-tv

Which TVs (brand/marks) can be programmed with use of the JavaScript/HTML5/CSS? We are doing Samsung SmartTV, LG SmartTV and waiting for Panasonic SDK, are there more of them? Can we also program in  JavaScript/HTML5/CSS STBs in order to bring the functionality to TVs, which do not allow development?

Comment: There's Philips NetTV as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Amino a140 STB if you want to provide a JavaScript/HTML5/CSS for your TV within an Opera browser with a full featured Video Player also for streams.

http://www.aminocom.com/products/a140/

Answer (score 5):

There is an update to my original question:

- **Samsung** SmartTV (Netcast) development is without any problem
- **LG** SmartTV development is without any problem
- **Panasonic** development is without any problem
- **Amino** development is without any problem
- **Loewe** does not have any SDK
- **Philips** NetTV seems to be pretty well maintained (we are just starting)
- **Sony** BRAVIA does not have any SDK, the only option left is use of the Yahoo! Connected TV widgets, which are limited to certain countries. The Sony support email is not working and Yahoo! does not have any official technical support.
- **Sony** GoogleTV (NSX-XXX) is option we did not check yet

Well those are our experiences from last 10 months of TV/STB development.

Regards,
STeN
info[at]mautilus.com

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the list XBOX 360

- **XBOX 360** development is without any problem, need to pay $99US annual membership.

And something new:

- **IKEA UPPLEVA** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Nm7-EuctOs Available in IKEA stores at the end of 2012

Comment: Hi, But Xbox development is problem in HTML isn't it? There is not any rendering engine in XNA as far as I know... Also Microsoft does not accept any software there, so this could be another issue with OTT on Xbox. Thanks for comments

Comment: With new software update XBOX 360 came with sth similar to the AppStore, so you can for sure post your own apps there. But yes it seems that you can't use HTML in XNA sadly.

Comment: Do you need a special XBox developer's model?